# How do I stop my content from overlapping when resizing browser vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to coding but I decided to make a personal practice website. My page looks fine on my computer but when I view it on a phone or resize my page vertically, all of my content starts to overlap. How can I prevent it from overlapping?

I've read that it might be an issue with having `position: absolute;` in my code but I'm not sure how I would replace that.

```html
<head>
    <style>
        .logo {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: block;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logosize {
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
}

.lower-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}

.location-text {
    font-size: 15px;
}

footer {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 97%;
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.footer ol {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.footer ol li {margin: 1em;}

.footer ol li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer ol li a:hover {color: rgb(83, 54, 150);}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="centered logosize">
        <p class="logo" id="typewriter">daniel m.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lower-center location-text">
        <p><span style='font-size:13px;'>&#128205;</span>
        las vegas
        <br>web developer _ creator</p>
    </div>
</body>
<footer class="footer">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="https://instagram.com/_ddmm"><img class="instagram-icon" src="images/instagram-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/_DDMM"><img class="twitter-icon" src="images/twitter-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/dannymaclaughlin"><img class="github-icon" src="images/github-icon.png"></a></li>
    </ol>
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to add all title elements inside the vertically centered `<div>` to prevent overlap.

As you resize the screen, the centered `<div>` will reposition itself according to the changes made. But what's inside the `<div>` will be unchanged. Think of it like a component or a piece of a puzzle, you structure it as you desire and then the piece responds as a whole to the external changes.

**Try the following snippet:**

```css
.logo {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
a:link {
    color: white;
}
a:visited {
    color: white;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.centered {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align:center;
}
.logosize {
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
}
.lower-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.location-text {
    font-size: 15px;
}
footer {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 97%;
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.footer ol {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
.footer ol li {margin: 1em;}
.footer ol li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.footer ol li a:hover {color: rgb(83, 54, 150);}
```

```html
<body style="vertical-align: middle;">
  
  <!--------- centered element -------->  
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="logosize">
        <span class="logo" id="typewriter">daniel m.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="location-text">
        <p><span style='font-size:13px;'>&#128205;</span>
        las vegas
        <br>web developer _ creator</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!----------------------------------->  

</body>

<footer class="footer">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="https://instagram.com/_ddmm"><img class="instagram-icon" src="images/instagram-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/_DDMM"><img class="twitter-icon" src="images/twitter-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/dannymaclaughlin"><img class="github-icon" src="images/github-icon.png"></a></li>
    </ol>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the below lines in the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

These enable responsiveness.

Then, in the `<body>` tag:

```
<div class="logosize">
    <span class="logo" id="typewriter">daniel m.</span>
</div>
<div class="lower-center location-text">
    <span>
        <span style='font-size:13px;'>&#128205;</span>
        las vegas
    </span>
    <span>web developer _ creator</span>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="https://instagram.com/_ddmm"><img class="instagram-icon" src="images/instagram-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/_DDMM"><img class="twitter-icon" src="images/twitter-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/dannymaclaughlin"><img class="github-icon" src="images/github-icon.png"></a></li>
    </ol>
</footer>
```

Notice, that `<footer>` should also be in the `<body>`. The rest code here is same, except that I've removed some unnecessary tags.

And finally changes in the CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

  /* Instead of display: block; Add the below lines: */

  height: 100vh; /* So body will have the full screen height */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* And the tags inside the body i.e. 2 divs and 1 footer - these will be aligned in a column and will be centered horizontally and vertically */
}

.centered {} /* No need of this */

.lower-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* With this, the 2 span's in this div will be aligned in a column and will be centered horizontally and vertically. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are aware of `display: flex` I would use that.  It is definitely better than the position absolute approach because items in a flex box will not collide.

Here is the solution I came up with using Flexbox, note a few things:

1. the `.centered` css declaration
2. I added a `<div class="centered">` around the two divs that originally had a centered class
3. Just a note: it's best practice to have everything that is visible to the user or a user might interact with (i.e. Javascript) within the `<body>` tag, so I moved the `<footer>` inside the body

```css
.logo {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: block;
}



.logosize {
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
}

.centered {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.location-text {
    font-size: 15px;
}

footer {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.footer ol {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.footer ol li {margin: 1em;}

.footer ol li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer ol li a:hover {color: rgb(83, 54, 150);}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <section class="centered">
        <div class="logosize">
            <p class="logo" id="typewriter">daniel m.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="location-text">
            <p><span style='font-size:13px;'>&#128205;</span>
            las vegas
            <br>web developer _ creator</p>
        </div>
    
    <footer class="footer">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="https://instagram.com/_ddmm"><img class="instagram-icon" src="images/instagram-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/_DDMM"><img class="twitter-icon" src="images/twitter-icon.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/dannymaclaughlin"><img class="github-icon" src="images/github-icon.png"></a></li>
    </ol>
</footer>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```